# Does C# OLE DB Syntax support joins?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oracle-apex

Maps, Forms, and Zone all follow the same general format:

```
FormType, 
ZoneID, 
*
```

The following query is designed to merge up these three tables's OTHER fields, along w/ FormType & ZoneID, represented by the *.  This query works in Oracle's Apex.  Is there any different syntax that should make it not work in C#'s OleDB api?

```
SELECT A.*, ZONE.VALUE 
FROM 
   (
      SELECT MAPS.*, FORMS.ZONEDESCRIPTION FROM MAPS LEFT JOIN FORMS
      ON (FORMS.FORMTYPE = MAPS.FORMTYPE AND FORMS.ZONEID = MAPS.ZONEID)
   ) A 
LEFT JOIN 
   ZONE
ON (A.FORMTYPE = ZONE.FORMTYPE AND A.ZONEID = ZONE.ZONEID)
```

I tried wrapping every table name in square brackets , but I continue to receive an 0x80004005 error.

Comment: All ADODB does is pass the query on to the underlying _provider_.  So it "supports" whatever the provider supports.  What provider are you using?

Comment: What is that error?  A connection type error?

Comment: Did you try running the same query directly on the db server? Try specfying column names instead of A.* and MAPS.*

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee796775(v=cs.20).aspx

> JOIN operations are not supported.

C# OleDB SQL syntax does not support joins, which I am currently using.

:(

Comment: That page is specifically for Commerce Server - Other OLEDB providers absolutely support `JOIN` syntax.